# apache 2 - how to access "mydomain.com" OR "www.mydomain.com"

Tags: apache-2.2

I've recently set up a domain name through godaddy.com.  I edited my A record to point to my servers IP address.  I then set up a sites-available file and symlinked that to the site-enabled directory.   When I go to the url "mydomain.com" I get the index.html file in /var/www/index.html which just says "No Direct Access."  When I go to the url "www.mydomain.com" I get my app properly.  My sites-available file for the domain is fairly basic, looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/my/app
    <Directory />
        ....
    </Directory>
    <Directory /path/to/my/app/>
        Option FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
```

When I try this sites-available file WITHOUT the www in the server name, I can not get to the app either way.  When I add the "www" to the server name (as it is above) I get the app, but can not then go to just "mydomain.com" or I get the "No Direct Access" error.  Anyone know how I can use either "www.mydomain.com" or just "mydomain.com" to access the site?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `ServerAlias`.

```
ServerName www.mydomain.com
ServerAlias mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
```

Make sure both your root domain and www point to the web server in your DNS.